# part of javascript array not being posted to server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a javascript array that looks like the following:

```
Array[
     0: "text1"
     1: "text2"
     2: "text3"
     app_name: "text4"
   ]
```

what is strange is the array only says it contains 3 items when i print it to the console. `Array[3]` but clearly it has 4 items.

when i do an ajax post of this data the `app_name` is not being transferred to the server. is this due to it being an object rather than an array? if so how would i post this to the server. I do not necessarily need the numeric indexes posted as well, just having the associative items would be best.

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
     url: path + "my/api/path",
     data: {"data": myarray}, 
     dataType: 'json',
     type: 'POST',
     success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
     }
  });
```

edit: i also should have mentioned I am using the handsontable plugin for jquery. this is the we the `getData` function returns the data from the spreadsheeet.

Comment: Try using an object rather than an array.

Comment: This is not a valid JS array :/

Answer (score 3):

While arrays in JavaScript *are* objects, it doesn't mean its wise to assign named properties to arrays, like you have done with `app_name`.

An array *length* will always only report the number of properly number-indexed elements (properties), not any named properties it has.

The same problem applies to JSON serialization: the JSON serializer will not serialize named properties of an array because JSON has no concept of named array properties.

For your sanity, I recommend avoiding using named properties on arrays altogether (there are times and places its useful, but you have to really know what you're doing).  I might recommend refactoring your code thusly:

```
var thing = {
    arr: [ 'text1', 'text2', 'text3' ],
    app_name: 'text4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON object.

```
var obj = {
    app_name: "text4",
    items: ["text1", "text2", "text3"]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Array count starts from 0-index, so, Array[3] shown is correct.
And to post app_data to the server, you must assign app_data to an index and then try, like this
3 : app_data
because array definition takes only for indexes not string.

hope this Helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

An Array only considers entries those with numerical and positive indexes. The length property will be equal to the greatest index + 1. If you do:

```
var arr = [];
arr[20] = 'twenty';
```

You'll see that `arr.length` will be 21, and the first 20 entries will be `undefined`.

I suggest that you use an object for your purpose.